# react-native-pager-view how to know to which direction the user is swiping?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i need to know to which direction the user is swiping, left or right. my initial thought was to save prev and current index with useRef hook and update them on each swipe using the onPageSelected callback. then i'd compare them to figure out which direction, but that just has its problems and is quite naive approach..

what can i do to figure this out?

current code goes like this

```
func component({stuff}){
    const currentIndex = useRef(null);
    const prevIndex = useRef(null);
    return <PagerView style={{ flex: 1 }}
        initialPage={currentPageNumber >= 1 ? 0 : 1}
        layoutDirection={"rtl"}
        onPageSelected={(PageSelectedEvent) => {
            prevIndex.current = currentIndex.current;
            currentIndex.current = PageSelectedEvent.nativeEvent.position;
            if (prevIndex.current > currentIndex.current) {
                if (currentPageNumber - 1 <= 0) {
                    setCurrentPageNumber(0);
                } else {
                    setCurrentPageNumber(currentPageNumber - 1);
                }
            } else if (prevIndex.current < currentIndex.current) {
                if (currentPageNumber + 1 >= 500) {
                    setCurrentPageNumber(500);
                } else {
                    setCurrentPageNumber(currentPageNumber + 1);
                }
            }
        }}
    >
        {pageComponents.map(page => {
            return page;
        })}
    </PagerView>

}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this task? May be it makes sense to try `onPageScroll` event with `e` argument that has `offset` value. As I remember this value changes from 0 to 1 during from left to right swipe and from 1 to 0 in other way.